# Developing a mobile website

Tags: 7, theming

I am using mobile tools module. It asks for path of mobile website. Does it mean that i need to develop mobile based pages again? i.e one for mobile and another for desktop ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mobile tools will let you differentiate between what you consider to be your 'desktop' version and your 'mobile' version via the theme you choose.  For example, www.example.org as your desktop and m.example.org as your mobile.

Mobile tools will try to redirect based on device detection, if you configure it that way.  If you want the desktop version to show on all devices, computer and mobile, you can configure it that way as well, or include the desktop version for 'desktop and mobile.'

But, if you do want a separate mobile theme, there are several existing mobile themes out for drupal.  To make that work you would have to install and enable the mobile theme, and then mobile tools will automatically select that theme when it detects the mobile based site.

Whatever version of the site you want to display on any device is very possible. It's just according to your goals for each device.

Comment: - So if i give like m.abc.com . So i have to develop this apart from drupal development rite ?

Comment: you would have to develop a new theme, yes, and then activate it. Mobile tools will then display the content in the theme for its respective devices. Aside from that, the content would be the same as it's coming from the same database, if that is what you re asking.

Comment: Hmm I could have been more clear there. All you are doing is designing two separate themes for the same Drupal installation. Then with mobile tools you are telling it how and when to select between the two themes, either device detection, or by specifying URL.

Comment: Theme thing i got u. But what about when its like m.abc.com . You mean to say when i access m.abc.com it will display same content in different theme ?

Comment: yup, that is correct. That is why you have to enable both themes. Mobile tools modules will detect that you are accessing m.abc.com and then automatically switch the theme to the mobile them for m.abc.com